# How to capture the desktop in OpenCV(c++)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I used c++ and opencv to capture the desktop screen, and I made the code 'hello world' to output when an image matching template.png appears on the screen. However, when I run this code, it keeps outputting hello world even though there is no image on the screen. What is the problem?
The full code is as below. I've tried several solutions on this site, but I don't know what the problem is.

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat hwnd2mat(HWND hwnd)
{
    HDC hwindowDC, hwindowCompatibleDC;

    int height, width, srcheight, srcwidth;
    HBITMAP hbwindow;
    Mat src;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;

    hwindowDC = GetDC(hwnd);
    hwindowCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
    SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC, COLORONCOLOR);

    RECT windowsize;    // get the height and width of the screen
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowsize);

    srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
    srcwidth = windowsize.right;
    height = windowsize.bottom / 1;  //change this to whatever size you want to resize to
    width = windowsize.right / 1;

    src.create(height, width, CV_8UC4);

    // create a bitmap
    hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hwindowDC, width, height);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/window/dd183402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    bi.biWidth = width;
    bi.biHeight = -height;  //this is the line that makes it draw upside down or not
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    // use the previously created device context with the bitmap
    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
    // copy from the window device context to the bitmap device context
    StretchBlt(hwindowCompatibleDC, 0, 0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0, srcwidth, srcheight, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow, 0, height, src.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);  //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow

    // avoid memory leak
    DeleteObject(hbwindow);
    DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindowDC);
    cvtColor(src, src, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    src.convertTo(src, CV_8U);

    return src;
}


void matchAndDisplay(Mat img, Mat templ)
{
    cvtColor(templ, templ, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    templ.convertTo(templ, CV_8U);
    Mat result;
    int result_cols = img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
    int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

    result.create(result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1);

    int match_method = TM_CCOEFF_NORMED;
    matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
    normalize(result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat());

    double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
    Point matchLoc;

    minMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat());

    if (match_method == TM_SQDIFF || match_method == TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)
    {
        matchLoc = minLoc;
    }
    else
    {
        matchLoc = maxLoc;
    }

    if (maxVal > 0.95)
    {
        cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HWND hwndDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    namedWindow("output", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    int key = 0;

    Mat templ = imread("template.png", IMREAD_COLOR);
    if (templ.empty()) {
        cerr << "Failed to open template.png" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (key != 27)
    {
        Mat src = hwnd2mat(hwndDesktop);
        if (!src.empty()) {
            matchAndDisplay(src, templ);
            imshow("output", src);
        }
        key = waitKey(60); // you can change wait time
    }
    return 0;
}
```